# Remove tabpage from tabcontrol using c# windows application

Tags: c#

I am using a tabcontrol, i want to remove a particular tab from the control.
The value i have to do this in a string which i dynamically.

How to remove the tab from tabcontrol using a existing tab name which i have in a string ??

The problem i am facing is..

I tried to use 
tabcontrol1.tabpages.remove(tabpage name);

In the above syntax i need to pass the tabpage name, but i have the value in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the tab page *name* or the tab page *text*?

If it is the name:

```
string tabToRemove = "tabPageName";
for (int i = 0; i < myTabControl.TabPages.Count; i++)
{
    if (myTabControl.TabPages[i].Name.Equals(tabToRemove, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        myTabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

If it is the text, you would simply use the `Text` property instead of the `Name` property.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that when you add a tabpage you use: `tabControl1.TabPages.Add(string text)`
Either try using: `tabControl.TabPages.Add(string key, string text)` then remove tabpages by key : `tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(string key)` (you can set `key` = `tabpage text` if they are all distinct)

or create a function that will find a tab by it's text:

```
    TabPage tp;
    foreach (TabPage ttp in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        if (ttp.Text == "tab text") tp = ttp;
        break;
    }
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tp);
```